# deleting multiplies ids with SQL (mailbox system)

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

```
<form method="post">
  <?php
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM test2 ORDER by id ASC"; 
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysql_error());

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
      echo '<table><tr>';
      echo '<td><input type="checkbox" id="'.$row['id'].'" name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'"></td>';
      echo '<td class="cEmne">'.$row['emne'].'</td>';
      echo '<td class="cBesked">'.$row['besked'].'</td>';
      echo '</tr></table>';       
  }

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM test2 WHERE id='$id'";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    echo "<script>window.location.href = 'index.php'</script>";
  }
  ?>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="slet">

</form>
```

Its only deleting the first checkbox that I checked.

I want to delete all the selected checkboxes.

Answer (score 2):

Use `name[]` notation for fields:

```
echo '<td><input type="checkbox" id="'.$row['id'].'" name="id[]" value="'.$row['id'].'"></td>';
                                                              ^----here
```

Then iterate through `$_POST['id']` as array and delete either each record or use `where id in`-statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the result from `$_POST` to be a string, so do the following:

```
$idList = implode ("','", $_POST['id']);
$sql = "DELETE FROM test2 WHERE id IN ('$idList')";
```